# C# how to read certain properties without knowling length

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I did a GET to the nuget api to get certain data about a package (in my case stylecop). The call works and i successfully get a json as a result. However the json is has a complex structure and i need to read out all items.

This is the api call i did, it works. This should show you the json im trying to get data from:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/stylecop.analyzers/index.json

The red area contains the item objects i want to read from. It has a total of 43 items in it. Every of these items has a commitId property. I want to read out all 43 commitId properties from every item to store them in a list.

[image: json screenshot]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/viEl2.jpg

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x);
   foreach (var item in dynJson)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.commitid);
                    }
```

This is what i've tried but i dont know how to access the 2nd layer of items

Comment: Hello, please provide a code sample demonstrating what you've tried

Comment: I did add it, i've forgot about it

Comment: Don't use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, that's best used when (in addition to not using `dynamic`) using a known model. Explore using `JObject.Parse()`.

Comment: If you copy the json to clipboard, then in visual studio click Edit>Paste Special>Paste Json as Classes you will get a model that you can deserialize too, much better and safer than using dynamic imo

Answer (score 0):

I see that JSON should be quite easy to create C# classes which you can deserialize into. You can use tool like jsonutils.com to generate C# model from your example JSON string and probably tweak it to better resemble your JSON structure.

Then you can deserialize it to C# object using:

```
var yourObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourJsonModel>(jsonString);
```

and access to any level you'd like via the object arrays/lists in the C# object.

Comment: have a look at Edit>Paste Special>Paste Json as Classes as Daniel stated